# Derive the Law of Conservation of energy from Newton's 3rd Law of Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation

I'd like to derive a conservation principle for the mechanical energy, as sum of kinetic and potential energy, for a multi-body point mass isolated system using the $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ Newton's principles of dynamics.

How can I do that?

Can I always find a conservation principle or do I need some assumption on the internal forces exchanged by the masses?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This question, in addition to being unclear, is impossible. Energy conservation does not come from Newtons 3rd law alone

Comment: How could second and third law combined. One states about change in motion while other conserved it.

Answer (score 3):

Given conservative forces:
$$
m\ddot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U(\mathbf{x})
$$
Rearranging the terms to one side and multiplying (as a scalar product) by $\dot{\mathbf{x}}$:
$$
m\ddot{\mathbf{x}}\dot{\mathbf{x}}+\nabla U(\mathbf{x})\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{m\dot{\mathbf{x}^2}}{2}+ U(\mathbf{x})\right)=0
$$
that is the energy in conservative system is conserved.
One could now follow the same procedure to add non-conservative forces - notably the Lorentz force (which doesn't change the energy) and friction (which leads to non-conservation) - I leave it as a homework :)

Comment: Would like to comment that U(x) in this context is not the potential function in general, but a specific path taken by an object through a potential gradient

Comment: but this is not the Newton's 3rd Law , this is Newton's second  Law

Comment: @Eli indeed, the first sentence in the OP contradicts to the second: Newton's 3rd law is for two interacting bodies, whereas energy conservation is for one.

Answer (score 1):

Although the microscopic formulation is nicer, the more commonly taught form is as follows:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr} =- [-\int_{a}^{b} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr}]$$

By the assumption of a Conservative force, there exists some potential function

$$\int_{a}^{b} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr}  = -[U(b)-U(a)]$$

By assuming F= ma

$$m\int_{a}^{b} \vec{a} \cdot \vec{dr}  = -[U(b)-U(a)]$$

$$m\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}} \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} \cdot \vec{v}dt  = -[U(b)-U(a)]$$

$$\frac{1}{2}m |\vec{v}(t_{1})|^2 -\frac{1}{2}m |\vec{v}(t_{1})|^2 = -[U(b)-U(a)]$$

$$\frac{1}{2}m |\vec{v}(t_{1})|^2  + U(b) = \frac{1}{2}m |\vec{v}(t_{1})|^2 + U(a)$$

The  sum of potential energy and kinetic  energy is one state is equal to the sum in some other state

Answer (score 0):

### Prelminiaries

There is not such a conservation law in general, while $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ Newton's principles can be used to derive the kinetic energy theorem for multi-body systems, that results in the formula

$\dot{K} = P^{tot} = P^{ext} + P^{int}$,

i.e. the time derivative of the total kinetic energy of a system $K$ equals the total power, both from internal and external actions, acting on the system.

A conservation principle for an isolated system can be derived only when the internal actions are conservative so that $P^{int}$ can be written as the time derivative of a potential energy, $P^{int} = -\dot{V}^{in}$. For isolated systems, $P^{ext} = 0$, with internal conservative actions it's possible to write

$0 = \dot{K} - P^{int} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left(K + V\right) = \dfrac{d E^{mech}}{dt}$.

### Details

Let's derive the theorem of kinetic energy for a system of point masses, and then find a conservation principle, under the assumption of conservative forces.

Let's consider a system composed of N point masses.
The Newton's second principle for particle $i$ reads

$\dot{\mathbf{Q}}_i = \mathbf{F}_i^{ext,i} = \mathbf{F}_i^{ext} + \sum_{j\ne i} \mathbf{F}_{ij}$,

being $\mathbf{Q}_i$ the momentum of the $i^{th}$ particle. Multiplying with the scalar product by the velocity of the mass $\mathbf{v}_i$, we get the balance equation for the kinetic energy of the $i^{th}$ mass, namely

$\dot{K}_i = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} m_i |\mathbf{v}_i|^2 \right) = \mathbf{v}_i \cdot \dot{\mathbf{Q}}_i = \mathbf{v}_i \cdot \mathbf{F}_i^{ext} + \mathbf{v}_i \cdot \sum_{j \ne i} \mathbf{F}_{ij} = P_i^{ext} + \mathbf{v}_i \cdot \sum_{j \ne i} \mathbf{F}_{ij}$.

Summing over all the particles, remembering that kinetic energy is an additive quantity,  $K = \sum_i K_i$, we get

$\dot{K} = \sum_i P_i^{ext} + \sum_i \mathbf{v}_i \cdot \sum_{j \ne i} \mathbf{F}_{ij} = P^{ext} + P^{int} = P^{tot}$.

Now we can exploit the third principle, namely $\mathbf{F}_{ij} = - \mathbf{F}_{ji}$, so that we can rewrite the power of internal forces as

$P^{int} = \sum_i \mathbf{v}_i \cdot \sum_{j \ne i}\mathbf{F}_{ij} = \sum_{\{i,j\}} (\mathbf{v}_i - \mathbf{v}_j) \cdot \mathbf{F}_{ij}$

summing over any pair $\{i,j\}$ of particles. This contribution is not zero in general, but only when the internal forces are conservative. As an example:

- with elastic springs $\mathbf{F}_{ij} = k_{ij} (\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_i)$, and thus

  $P^{int} = \sum_{\{i,j\}} k_{ij}(\mathbf{v}_i - \mathbf{v}_j) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_i) = - \sum_{\{i,j\}} \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} |\mathbf{r}_j - \mathbf{r}_i|^2 \right) = - \dfrac{d}{dt} \sum_{\{i,j\}}  V_{ij}^{el} = -\dfrac{d V^{int, el}}{dt}$

  the power of internal forces can be written as the time derivative of a internal elastic potential energy $V^{int,el}$. In this case, it's possible to put the contribution of the internal conservative force on the left-hand side of the equation and define the mechanical energy of the system as the sum of the kinetic energy and the internal elastic energy, $E^{mech} = K + V^{int,el}$, so tha the equation becomes

  $\dot{E}^{mech} = P^{ext}$.

  So, if all the internal forces are conservative, you can define a internal potential and a total mechanical energy that is conserved if the power of external force is zero.

If the internal forces are not conservative, like velocity dependent forces from linear dampers, $\mathbf{F}_{ij} = c (\mathbf{v}_j - \mathbf{v}_i)$, you can't define a potential energy from the internal forces, while the internal power is always negative, or at least non positive,

$P^{int} = \sum_{\{i,j\}}c_{ij} (\mathbf{v}_j - \mathbf{v}_i) \cdot (\mathbf{v}_i - \mathbf{v}_j) = - \sum_{\{i,j\}} c_{ij} |\mathbf{v}_j - \mathbf{v}_i|^2 := - 2 D \le 0$.

having defined $D \ge 0$ as the dissipation, corresponding to a term that makes the kinetic energy decrease.

Comment: What is the question for this answer?

Comment: Deriving the conservation of energy for isolated multi-body systems, exploiting the $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ Newton's principle. As I wrote in the answer, the theorem of kinetic energy always holds, while there is not such a conservation law for the mechanical energy in the general case, but only in the case of potential internal forces.

Comment: Anyway, I've understood the game is rigged and moderators colluding with a bunch of friends. Too bad, for people they think at themselves as smart people of science...

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL. Rage and revenge anonymous downvoting

Comment: And deleting answer...@Eli, where have you gone?