# The Newton’s equation from energy conservation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

When a mass particle is moving along a path $x(t)$ in the presence of conservative force, the energy is conserved, i.e., $\Delta T + \Delta V = 0$, where $T(\dot x)$ is the kinetic energy and $V(x)$ is the potential energy. Is the following straightforward derivation of the Newton’s equation meaningful?

$\Delta T +\Delta V =0$

$ \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}m(\dot x+d \dot x)^2-\frac{1}{2}m{\dot x}^2 + V(x+dx)-V(x) = 0$

$ \Rightarrow \frac{\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x+d \dot x)^2-\frac{1}{2}m{\dot x}^2}{dx} + \frac{V(x+dx)-V(s)}{dx} = 0$

$ \Rightarrow \frac{\frac{1}{2}m(\dot x+d \dot x)^2-\frac{1}{2}m{\dot x}^2}{( \dot x / \ddot x)d \dot x} + \frac{V(x+dx)-V(x)}{dx}=0$

$(d \dot x=\ddot x dt\rightarrow 0 \space \space \text{and} \space \space dx=\dot x dt\rightarrow 0, \space \space \text{as} \space \space dt\rightarrow 0 )$

$ \Rightarrow (\ddot x/\dot x) D[\frac{1}{2}m{\dot x}^2] + D[V(x)] =0$

$ \Rightarrow m\ddot x + \frac{dV(x)}{dx} = 0.$

Moreover, can we derive the classica path $x(t)$, where $x(t_0) = x_0$, by solving the differential equation $T[\dot{x}(t) + \ddot{x}(t)]-T[\dot{x}(t)] + V[x(t)+\dot{x}(t)] - V[x(t)] = 0.$

Comment: 1. N2L holds for more than the energy conservation case, and has a far greater logical framework for general solutions to mechanical problems, so your derivation is of little use. 2. Your result is known to anybody who did any Lagrangian and especially Hamiltonian mechanics. 3. It is actually wrong, because N2L is in terms of momentum, and works even when mass is changing, which you are assuming is not changing.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Ok. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: You have rediscovered one of [Hamilton's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics#From_Euler-Lagrange_equation_to_Hamilton's_equations)

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes, in 1D.

Comment: Related: [Derive the Law of Conservation of energy from Newton's 3rd Law of Motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/740373/247642)